# Ansible - GCP Dynamic inventory & tags

Tags: ansible, google-cloud-platform

I'm just getting started with ansible and have successfully been able to configure ansible to get dynamic inventory from GCP.

I am able to successfully run the ping module against all instances:

```
ansible -i ~/git/ansible/inventory all -m ping
```

I am also able to successfully run the ping module against a single instance based on hostname:

```
ansible -i ~/git/ansible/inventory instance-2 -m ping
```

I would now like to utilize tags to group instances. For example, I have set of instances that are labeled 'env:dev' 
https://www.evernote.com/l/AfcLWLkermxMyIK7GvGpQXjXdIDFVAiT_z0

I have attempted multiple variations of the command below with no luck

```
ansible -i ~/git/ansible/inventory tag_env:dev -m ping
```

How can I filter and group my dynamic inventory on GCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to add network tag in instance settings not labels i don't know why but gce.py doesn't return GCP labels so you can only  use network tags wich is limited (i mean not key=value but just value)
For example add network tag just 'dev' and then run `ansible -i ~/git/ansible/inventory tag_dev -m ping` 
also if you need to filter by few tags only way i found it's

```
- name: test stuff   
  hosts: tag_api:&tag_{{ environment }}   
  var_files:
    vars/{{ environment }}
    vars/api

  tasks:
    - name: test
      command: echo "test"
```

run playbook like this `ansible-playbook -i inventory/ -u user playbook/test.yml -e environment=dev`

maybe someone know better way,  with `aws ec2.py` i could filter in `ec2.ini` config but `gce.py` very limited
also i noticed that sometimes you need to clear cache `gce.py --refresh-cache`